# Array.create and jagged array

Tags: arrays, f#

Can't understand the reason of such behavior:

```
let example count = 
    let arr = Array.create 2 (Array.zeroCreate count)
    for i in [0..count - 1] do
        arr.[0].[i] <- 1
        arr.[1].[i] <- 2
    arr

example 2 |> Array.iter(printfn "%A")
```

Print:

```
[|2; 2|]
[|2; 2|]
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/borMmO

If I replace:

```
let arr = Array.create 2 (Array.zeroCreate count)
```

to:

```
let arr = Array.init 2 (fun _ -> Array.zeroCreate count)
```

Everything will work as expected:

```
let example count = 
    let arr = Array.init 2 (fun _ -> Array.zeroCreate count)
    for i in [0..count - 1] do
        arr.[0].[i] <- 1
        arr.[1].[i] <- 2
    arr

example 2 |> Array.iter(printfn "%A")
```

Print:

```
[|1; 1|]
[|2; 2|]
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/uXmlbn

I think the reason is the fact that the array - a reference type. But I want to understand why this is happening. Since I didn't expect such results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you write:

```
let arr = Array.create 2 (Array.zeroCreate count)
```

You are creating an array where each element is a reference to *the same array*. This means that mutating a value using `arr.[0]` also mutates the value in `arr.[1]` - because the two array elements are pointing to the same mutable array. You end up with:

```
[| x  ; x |]
    \  /
 [| 0; 0 |]
```

When you write:

```
let arr = Array.init 2 (fun _ -> Array.zeroCreate count)
```

The provided function is called for each position in the `arr` array and so you'll end up with different array for each element (and so `arr.[0] <> arr.[1]`). You end up with:

```
     [| x ;  y |]
       /       \
[| 0; 0 |]   [| 0; 0 |]
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought something like this, but it was not obvious to me =) Now I understand.