# F# jagged array assignment

Tags: f#, jagged-arrays

I am getting strange behavior - when I assign a single value to a jagged array, it changes values of the entire column.

```
let testArray = Array.create 5 (Array.create 5 nan)
testArray.[3].[3] <- 1.0
```

The code above, instead of changing the value of a single cell, changes the value of the entire column.

```
val it : float [] [] =
  [|[|nan; nan; nan; 1.0; nan|]; [|nan; nan; nan; 1.0; nan|];
  [|nan; nan; nan; 1.0; nan|]; [|nan; nan; nan; 1.0; nan|];
  [|nan; nan; nan; 1.0; nan|]|]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array.create and jagged array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252606/array-create-and-jagged-array)

Answer (score 13):

This happens because you're not creating a 2-dimensional array (as I assume you expect), but rather you're creating exactly two arrays: one array with 5 `nan`s in it, and another array with 5 references to the first array in it. Just to illustrate the matter, the following code is completely equivalent to yours:

```
let firstArray = Array.create 5 nan
let testArray = Array.create 5 firstArray
testArray.[3].[3] <- 1.0
```

So that the line `testArray.[3].[3] <- 1.0` actually changes only one element - the fourth one in `firstArray`, but if you then try to print out `testArray`, that same element shows up multiple times, because there are multiple references to `firstArray`.

If you wanted to create an array with five different arrays in it, you need to use `Array.init`, which instead of the element takes a "create next element" function:

```
let testArray = Array.init 5 (fun _ -> Array.create 5 nan)
```

Alternatively, you can use list comprehension to create the array:

```
let testArray = [|for i in 1..5 -> Array.create 5 nan|]
```

Both will give you the same result, though the first one will have slightly better performance.

If you really need to work with two-dimensional arrays (rather than arrays of arrays), you might want to look at `Array2D` instead:

```
let testArray = Array2D.create 5 5 nan
testArray.[3,3] <- 1.0
```